# how to structure an example of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find an example of a sequence that on the one hand is divergent and on the other hand has two subsequences that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathit{a}_{3n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \mathit{a}_{5n}.$$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean $n$ where you wrote $x$?

Comment: Easy: make a sequence $a_n$ that takes one value when $n$ is divisible by $3$ or $5$, but takes another value when $n$ is divisible by neither.

Answer (score 4):

What about $1,2,0,4,0,0,7,8,0,0,11,0,13...$?

Comment: this doesn't work because of "6", "9", "10"  is also part of the subsequence so you get divergent

Comment: @ShaharFeingold:  thank you for pointing out my error; I have corrected it

Comment: that seems right but how do prove that the sequence is divergent

Comment: it's not a Cauchy sequence, for one thing

Comment: If it had a limit $L$, then, for any $\epsilon>0, $ there would be $N$ such that, for all $n\ge N $, $|a_n-L|\lt \epsilon$.  But for any arbitrarily large $m$, $a_{15m+1}-a_{15m}=(15m+1)-0$, so it can't be that $|a_{15m+1}-L|$ and $|a_{15m}-L|$ are both $\lt\epsilon$ if $\epsilon<1, $ say

Answer (score 2):

Let $$a_n=\begin{cases}1, \text{if } 3\mid n \text{ or }5\mid n \\0, \text{otherwise }\end{cases},$$
then $a_{3n}=a_{5n}=1$ for all $n$ and hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathit{a}_{3n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \mathit{a}_{5n}$$ but $a_n$ doesn't converge.

Comment: how do you prove that the sequence is divergent

Comment: @ShaharFeingold, since it has a subsequence which doesn't converge.